# CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION BSOD at random windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod, hp-pavilion

I have a new, off the shelf windows 8.1 computer.
 It's an HP-15 PC, product number J9M24UA#ABA.
 I can supply serial number if required.
It is a 64 bit pc.
  I recently installed Daemon tools. I started getting BSODs.
I did a windows refresh, it still comes up with a BSODs.
I've looked everywhere and found nobody else has this issue.
It doesn't leave a mark in the logs (it just says error 0 and doing a memory scan reveals NOTHING).
 It seems aggravated by three things, **audio**, **any form of external storage (USB, disks, emulated ISO files), and random spikes in the CPU and RAM.**
It still also does it randomly.
I have no indication, and it gets on my nerves.
**How can I stop this?**
Mini dumps are here(Also includes the SYSTEM.SAV file):http://www.mediafire.com/download/3sdacymu0z8tqk3/Windows_8.1_Error.7z

Comment: share (onedrive, dropbox) the dmp files from C:\windows\minidump

Comment: I don't have a onedrive or dropbox account but I do have a mediafire account. Here's the file you're looking for(and backup too, SYSTEM.SAV, the one that I've been told to go look at numerous times by other websites). http://www.mediafire.com/download/3sdacymu0z8tqk3/Windows_8.1_Error.7z

Comment: hm, I also need the memory.dmp from C:\Windows to see more. the minidumps don't include all required data.

Comment: Huh. Well, after 50 different retries I fixxed it for a registry error in the bios EPROM. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: post the steps you did to fix the issue as answer

Comment: Gosh, it's been forever since I've been on here. I had to go into the BIOS and change the BIOS clock. Not sure why, but it was synced to 9999... and if you don't realize, as soon as you go over that year, it absolutely breaks your computers. I'm not even sure how the heck that happened, however, my OS clock was displaying just fine, which made it weirder. I'd recall more details if I could, but I can't. The computer doesn't even function anymore with a hole burned right through it's hard drive. GG Asus, you made a faulty computer that barely lasted a year.

Comment: ok, post this as answer so that other can find it easier. searching comments is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem most people will most likely not encounter and probably was just a manufacturing defect.

You'll need to boot into the BIOS(which you can get to by means provided by your BIOS developers. Look it up on your phone to figure out how you access it as it can be different for different computers), and look at the BIOS clock. If it says xx/xx/9999, you need to change that to the current year.

That's all. Computers freak when the date goes over 9999(see what happens to Windows XP as that's one of the only ways you can get that to work)

Yeah it's a pretty simple problem and I should've caught that myself.